# How can forcibly get an OCaml function to return an int type value instead of unit?

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml.

I am working on some code in which the following function is nested inside another function, which must return an int type value.

```
Asn(x,e) ->
      let v = eval e in
        Array.set vararr x+1 v
```

vararr is a global array already declared and initialised above.

In this function, I want to set an element of the array using "Array.set vararr x+1 v", but I want the function to return the value v. How can I do that?

**Update:**

I changed it to:

```
Asn(x,e) ->
      let v = eval e in
        Array.set vararr x+1 v; 
      v
```

The error for "Array.set vararr x+1 v;" is:

```
This expression has type int -> unit
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

I think the problem isn't what Asn returns. The problem is with what "Array.set vararr x+1 v;" returns. This is very strange! Why does "Array.set vararr x+1 v;" have to return an int type value?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this:

```
let v = eval e in
Array.set vararr (x + 1) v;
v
```

**Update**

Don't forget parentheses around `(x + 1)`.

The expression:

```
Array.set vararr x+1 v
```

Is parsed like this:

```
(Array.set vararr x) + (1 v)
```

Function application in OCaml has very high precedence.

The `+` operator wants an int at the left but you have a function there.

Generally speaking, you just need to get used to OCaml syntax. It's not so bad after a little experience.

Comment: What if I use ;; here instead of ;? What really is the difference between ;; and ; in this case?

Comment: Uh oh! I am still getting the same error. I'll update the question in 1 minute.